# Remove first line from HTML Markup Field using RegEx

Tags: html, regex, markup

I have a single text field that contains HTML markup. The system that generates this field content always seems to generate a first line with a non-visible carriage return value in it and I can't seem to prevent if from doing so.

Does anyone know of a way (perhaps using a Regular Expression), to remove that first line from this text field?

I'd prefer to leave all other instances of the carriage return values in the field as is, so if it's a RegEx statement that will just remove the first line of a text field, that would work for me.

Any suggestions most welcomed.

Cheers,

Wayne

Comment: What language do you use? In PHP you just may use trim()

Comment: A regex seems like overkill to simply trim off a single character from a potentially large chunk of HTML. Not sure what language you're using, but see if there's a TrimStart() method or similar. Or you could index your string from position 1 instead of 0. i.e. myString[1, mystring.Length]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `trim` (often removes whitespaces, CR ) method is used for this in many programming languages. You did not state in what language you will be doing this...